# android: listview load incorrectly

Tags: android, listview

My listview load properly but when I go back to my MainActivity then again go to ViewAll activity then it load incorrectly like below.[image]

Here is my ViewAll activity where I have load `list view`.

```
public class ViewAll extends Activity {
    private ListView listView;
    public ArrayList<Model> arrayList;
    private Database_Handler database_handler;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    private long i = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        addNewData();

        database_handler = new Database_Handler(ViewAll.this);
        db = database_handler.getReadableDatabase();
        arrayList = database_handler.getAllContacts();
        adapter = new MyAdapter(ViewAll.this, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                try {
                    database_handler = new Database_Handler(ViewAll.this);
                    db = database_handler.getReadableDatabase();
                    arrayList = database_handler.getAllContacts();
                    adapter = new MyAdapter(ViewAll.this, arrayList);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void addNewData() {
        try {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    String str1 = "List "+i+" ", str2 = "Handler testing";

                    database_handler = new Database_Handler(ViewAll.this);
                    db = database_handler.getWritableDatabase();
                    database_handler.addRegister(str1, str2, db);
                    database_handler.close();

                    handler.postDelayed(this, 60 * 10);
                  i++;
                }
            }, 60 * 10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my `adapter`.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Model> arrayList;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MyAdapter(ViewAll viewAll, ArrayList<Model> arrayList) {
        this.context = viewAll;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public class Holder {
        TextView tvFirstName,tvLastName;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View myView = null;
        try {
            Holder holder;
            myView = convertView;
            if (myView == null) {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter, null);
                holder = new Holder();
                holder.tvFirstName= (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);
                holder.tvLastName= (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvLastName);
                myView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (Holder) myView.getTag();
            }
            holder.tvFirstName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getF_name());
            holder.tvLastName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getL_name());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myView;
    }
}
```

Actually I am inserting data into database using handler class and show all data into listview in my ViewAll activity and it work fine but when i go to my previous MainActivity and again go to ViewAll activity then listview load incorrectly which show in the image like after "List 24" data inserted incorrectly.

Comment: Clear arrayList before addnewdata funstion

Comment: Correct. `addNewData` will be called every time the `ViewAll` activity is created. I'd rather move the database population to be independent of the activity (eg, on app launch, at which point you replace the old data instead of appending)

Answer (score 1):

Please Clear your Arraylist and also clear your adapter when you are loading it from first item of listview.

You can clear this by lstVwList.setAdapter(null);

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but please put this as comment rather then considering it as answer, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much  Akshay it is working fine. I appreciate your help.